# Why is my webpage turning blue

Tags: html, background, embed, media

Here is a link to the website http://alohavirtual.virtual-aviation.org/ it just started turning blue a few weeks ago. I looked at the code there is nothing that would make it do this. There is supposed to be text but the blue is covering up everything, this is really something i have never seen before.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>

<head>
  <title>Aloha Virtual Splash</title>
</head>

<body>
<center> <img src="http://virtual-aviation.org/alohavirtual/500px-Aloha_Airlines_Logo.png"></br>     </center>
<center><font size="6"></font><b><font face="Arial" size="38" color="#000000">E komo mai</font></b></br>
<font face="Arial Narrow" size="5" color="#000000"><p>Aloha Virtual Coming Soon</p]></font></center>
<!-- HTML Codes by Quackit.com -->
<embed src="http://alohavirtual.virtual-aviation.org/tradhawiianmedley.mp3" autoplay="true" hidden="false" loop="true" width="1" height="1" align="center" name="MusicPlayer" volume="10"></embed>
<font face="Cambria"><center></br>Aloha Airlines Virtual is not related to real world aviation includeing Aloha Airlines, Aloha Island Air, Island Air, or Aloha Air Cargo.</center></font>
</br><font face="Cambria" color="#000000"><center>All rights reserverd Virtual Aviation Experience 2011  </center></font>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: tried it with: Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Firefox for Linux and Chromium for linux, IE9. and all of them seem fine

Comment: I tried it with chrome on two different computers.

Comment: Also there's a typo in the bottom line: "All rights reserverd" should be "reserved"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I opened your website up in Chrome 17 for Linux and experienced the Blue effect.

I inspected the DOM and the problem appears to be caused by the following embed:

```
<embed src="http://alohavirtual.virtual-aviation.org/tradhawiianmedley.mp3" autoplay="true" hidden="false" loop="true" width="1" height="1" align="center" name="MusicPlayer" volume="10">
```

Once I removed this element from the DOM the blue went away (and the annoying music stopped)

I can't tell you *why* it's causing the blue problem, all I can tell you is that it is the culprit.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be failing to load: tradhawiianmedley.mp3

If I remove this node from the dom its no longer blue:

```
<video controls="" autoplay="" style="margin: auto; position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;" name="media" src="http://alohavirtual.virtual-aviation.org/tradhawiianmedley.mp3"></video>
```